# How to return the AJAX value in extJS?

Tags: ajax, extjs

I am calling AJAX request and getting the value as well as a response but I want to return the value and store in a variable. I tried so many ways but its not working. PFB the code snippet.

```
submitRequest: function(type, url) {
    var maxValue = this.getMaxValue(PORTALURL.EXCEPTION.MAX_VALUE);
    if(grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection().length > maxValue){
        Ext.Msg.alert('Alert!', type + ' count is more than 10');
        return;
    }
}, 
getMaxValue : function(url){
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: url,
        success: function(response) {
            var result = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            //callback(result); Not working
            // return result; Not Working
        }
    });
}
```

How I can get the value in `var maxValue` ?

Appreciate all your help.

Comment: check your are able to get data from server, check console if there is any error then check network whether request response is coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an Ajax request is asynchrone you can use a callback:

```
submitRequest: function(type, url) {
    this.getMaxValue(PORTALURL.EXCEPTION.MAX_VALUE, function(maxValue){ // <<== Your callback
        if(grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection().length > maxValue){
            Ext.Msg.alert('Alert!', type + ' count is more than 10');
            return;
        }
    });
}, 
getMaxValue : function(url, callback){
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: url,
        success: function(response) {
            var result = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            callback(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Still maxValue is getting as Undefined.

Comment: @SandeepChoudhari oups! i edited my answer it should works now

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Ext JS 6 you may also use promises with Ext.Ajax.request() out of the box which may help you to organise your code in a more 'straightforward' way and get rid of a so-called 'callback hell'.

```
submitRequest: function(type, url) {
    this.getMaxValue(PORTALURL.EXCEPTION.MAX_VALUE).then(function(response) {
        var maxValue = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        if (grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection().length > maxValue){
            Ext.Msg.alert('Alert!', type + ' count is more than 10');
            return;
        }
    }).done();    
}, 

getMaxValue : function(url) {
    return Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: url,
        ...
    })
}
```

For the further reading I would recommend you the following article https://www.sencha.com/blog/asynchronous-javascript-promises/

Comment: Thanks @fen1ksss. Its working without callback. I have another question over here. I want to hold the other process till AJAX response will complete. How I can achieve that.

Comment: You need to call that other process from 'then' block of your fulfilled promise, the same way you are calling Ext.Msg.alert above.